# Why doesn't the GetWindowThreadProcessId function work with the command line?

Tags: c++, windows, process

When I try to use the GetWindowThreadProcessId function, it fails and using the GetLastError function and turning it into a string it says "The Parameter is Incorrect". It finds the window fine, and I have tried changing the HWND parameter to an opened .txt file and it seems to work fine, so I think the problem is with the command line and nothing else. Here is my code:

```
HWND win = FindWindowA(NULL, (LPCSTR)"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");
        LPSTR str;
        str = new CHAR[50];
        GetWindowTextA(win, str, 49);
        cout << str;
        LPDWORD * pid;
        pid = new LPDWORD();
        DWORD cmdthread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(win, *pid);
        cout << GetLastErrorAsString();
```

It seems to work fine with anything that is not a Windows command prompt, but I need to use the Command Prompt. Is there any kind of work around or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Take another look at the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa). Your argument is not at all what the documentation describes (or I'm misremembering what cmd used to put in its title). In addition, the cast is very suspicious because it is redundant in this case and could be actively harmful depending what you're casting. There's also no apparent reason to be `new`ing pointers in this code—you can get pointers to stack variables. In fact, `new`ing pointers this way is giving you extra problems that wouldn't be there otherwise.

Comment: The answer is what I'd go with, but all I can really recommend in general is learning C++ from a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (far enough to get to the C side of things as well) before delving into the Windows API because confusion around language concepts will make the API even harder to use than it is already. It can also be useful compiling with your compiler's sanitizers enabled because this type of code can be rather error-prone, especially early on and that will catch some memory errors and the like.

Comment: For the Windows API specifically, Charles Petzold's *Programming Windows* is very popular for general knowledge. However, if I remember right, it is best read when familiar with C. These APIs in particular are as old as time and Windows's backward compatibility story means that his old books still apply when working with the old APIs directly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. These books will definitely help me :p

Comment: You should only use the result of `GetLastErrorAsString()` *if there was an error.* If there wasn't, you are only getting it for the *previous* error, or an error the API may have generated internally.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an invalid `DWORD*` pointer to the 2nd parameter of `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`.  Try this instead:

```cpp
HWND win = FindWindowA(NULL, "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");
if (win != NULL)
{
    // this part is redundant, since you just did a search for
    // the HWND by its window text, so you already know what
    // the text is...
    char str[50] = {};
    GetWindowTextA(win, str, 49);
    cout << str;
    //

    DWORD pid = 0;
    DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(win, &pid);
    if (tid != 0)
        cout << "Thread ID: " << tid << " Process ID: " << pid;
    else
        cout << GetLastErrorAsString();
}
```

Comment: That seems to work. When I try to attach that to the main thread it fails with the same error, though: AttachThreadInput(mainthread, tid, true);

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` report if `AttachThreadInput()` fails? Note that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput) does say you can't attach a system thread to another thread, or attach another thread to a system thread. The command window is a system component, so you might not be allowed to attach to it. On the other hand, `AttachThreadInput()` can also fail if the target thread simply doesn't have a message queue to attach to.

Comment: It says "The parameter is incorrect" I read the documentation for a lot of these things, but couldn't find out what is/isn't a system thread, but if the command prompt is I guess I'm out of luck. Do you know if there's any way of running command prompts concurrently and closing specific ones? That is sort of the goal here.